# Fewer subclasses generated than requested using MatchIt subclassification

Tags: r, matching, propensity-score-matching

I am trying to do a propensity score stratification using `MatchIt::matchit(method = "subclass")`. I want to understand why I get a warning message:
`Due to discreteness in the distance measure, fewer subclasses were generated than were requested.`, while [the package describes](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/matching-methods.html#subclassification-method-subclass)

> by default, matchit() moves a unit from an adjacent subclass into the
> lacking one to ensure that each subclass has at least one unit from
> each treatment group.

I also looked into the [source code](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/blob/master/R/matchit2_methods.R), which is consistent with the quote above.

> If any subclasses don't have members of a treatment group, fill them by "scooting" units from nearby subclasses until each subclass has a unit from each treatment group

I know this is very data dependent, and I can not share my data with the public. So here is a non-reproducible code:

```
m_out <- matchit(treat ~ var1 + var2 + var3, data = mydata, estimand = "ATE", 
                 method = "subclass", distance = "glm", discard = "both", min.n = 1, subclass = 5)
```

The code above result in warning and only produce 4 strata while requested 5. Why isn't any unit scooted? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is quite hard to diagnose this without the data. One possibility is that the propensity score doesn't take on enough values for 5 subclasses. For example, if the propensity score only takes on 4 values, you would only see 4 subclasses, even if you requested 5.

Feel free to submit an issue [here](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues) and I can take a look. Even if you can't include the data, it would be extremely helpful if you could include the propensity score and treatment variable.